# using Wasm can avoid Hard fork?

Tags: ewasm, wasm

Is it possible if we use wasm in blockchain can we avoid hard fork, If it's possible how does it work? I read in parity ethereum whitepaper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the consensus mechanism is stored in the blockchain as WASM code and every client comes with a WASM interpreter, no forks are required anymore since every client can fallback to WASM code in the blockchain if it figures out it's own local consensus rule is outdated.

Example:

1. Client verifies block using it's local consensus rules
2. Client fails to verify block
3. Client tries to verify block using the last updated WASM consensus code on the blockchain - this is slow
4. Client succeeds verifying this block and signals the maintainer that it's own
   consensus rules are outdated, an update is required
5. Client goes on to use WASM consensus code of the blockchain
6. Maintainer updates client
7. Client uses own native consensus rules - it is much faster because it is optimized and compiled code

As far as I know Parity presented this approach in a blockchain creation tool called "substrate" they invented. You can watch a video of it on YouTube: [Rob Habermeier presents Parity Substrate: the foundation for blockchain innovators](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q1zLHO7Lkuk). I really recommend this video to anybody in the blockchain space, because this is some innovative cool piece of technology in my opinion.

Comment: Hi thanks for this great explanation and link which you provided, Is there any demo or example just to try it.

Comment: @fama Yes, but since it is in early stage this requires a bit of effort: https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/creating-your-first-substrate-chain
At the end you can see that there is an Substrate UI, through which you can upgrade the runtime, including the consensus rules.